# Convert API response data (Bytes) to dict in Python

Tags: python, json

```
URL = "API URL"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
standards = response.read() #returning type <bytes>
standards = standards.decode('utf-8') #converting type <str>
```

I actually want to read through the data and extract the values of "referenceNumber" & "title" from the data given below, I have 755 records of same structure. I want to extract the above given fields for each record.

`[{"larsCode":0,"referenceNumber":"ST0870","title":"Business support assistant","status":"Withdrawn","url":"https://www.instituteforapprenticeships.org/api/apprenticeshipstandards/0","versionNumber":"0.0","change":"Withdrawn","changedDate":"2019-07-31T00:00:00","earliestStartDate":null,"latestStartDate":null,"latestEndDate":null,"overviewOfRole":"","level":2,"typicalDuration":0,"maxFunding":0,"route":"Business and administration","keywords":["Business","support","assistant","admin","office","office administration"],"jobRoles":[],"entryRequirements":"","assessmentPlanUrl":"","ssa1":"","ssa2":"","version":"0.0","standardInformation":"","occupationalSummary":"","knowledges":[],"behaviours":[],"skills":[],"options":[],"optionsUnstructuredTemplate":[]]`

Answer (score 0):

The server returns json encoded bytes. Python has a module for json.

You dont need to convert it to `str` in order to decode the json bytes.

Look at the python documentation for handling json objects.

Specifically `json.loads` for handling `str` or `json.load` for handling file like objects.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads

Just an fyi, your response is a list of objects so `json.loads` will return a `list` of `dict`.

Comment: `   URL = "https://www.instituteforapprenticeships.org/api/apprenticeshipstandards"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    standards = response.read()
    standards = json.loads(standards)`

Comment: The code above shows the following error:
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

Comment: That is a server side error. Nothing to do with the code you have posted. Also I got ssl certificate expired errors when connecting to that server. I created a new ssl context that ignores certificates and ran the code and it works fine.

Comment: [
  { 
      
    "first_name": "Katie",  
    "last_name": "Rodgers"
  },
  
  { 
      
    "first_name": "Naomi",  
    "last_name": "Green"
  },
]

I'm getting the record in this format, How can I read each record from the list?

Comment: Its a list, you need to iterate over it. Look into `for loops` in python